# OOM despite the large amount of free SWAP

Tags: oom

During some ML training `htop` shows usage of all RAM (16GB) and only 2G (out of 16GB) of SWAP when OOM happens.

`dmesg` shows:

```
[pon sie 12 11:53:44 2019] Purging GPU memory, 0 bytes freed, 131072 bytes still pinned.
[pon sie 12 11:53:44 2019] 73728 and 0 bytes still available in the bound and unbound GPU page lists.
[pon sie 12 11:53:44 2019] iscsid invoked oom-killer: gfp_mask=0x24200ca, order=0, oom_score_adj=0
[pon sie 12 11:53:44 2019] iscsid cpuset=/ mems_allowed=0
[pon sie 12 11:53:44 2019] CPU: 1 PID: 1306 Comm: iscsid Tainted: P           OE   4.4.0-116-generic #140-Ubuntu
[pon sie 12 11:53:44 2019] Hardware name: MSI MS-7996/H110M PRO-VD (MS-7996), BIOS 2.E0 08/11/2017
[pon sie 12 11:53:44 2019]  0000000000000286 faad9ce5c4d517dc ffff8804677a79d8 ffffffff813ffc13
[pon sie 12 11:53:44 2019]  ffff8804677a7b90 ffff880464551e00 ffff8804677a7a48 ffffffff8121012e
[pon sie 12 11:53:44 2019]  0000000000000015 0000000000000000 ffff88046464f300 ffff880463138000
[pon sie 12 11:53:44 2019] Call Trace:
[pon sie 12 11:53:44 2019]  [<ffffffff813ffc13>] dump_stack+0x63/0x90
[pon sie 12 11:53:44 2019]  [<ffffffff8121012e>] dump_header+0x5a/0x1c5
[pon sie 12 11:53:44 2019]  [<ffffffff81397c44>] ? apparmor_capable+0xc4/0x1b0
[pon sie 12 11:53:44 2019]  [<ffffffff811968f2>] oom_kill_process+0x202/0x3c0
[pon sie 12 11:53:44 2019]  [<ffffffff81196d19>] out_of_memory+0x219/0x460
[pon sie 12 11:53:44 2019]  [<ffffffff8119cd45>] __alloc_pages_slowpath.constprop.88+0x965/0xb00
[pon sie 12 11:53:44 2019]  [<ffffffff8119d168>] __alloc_pages_nodemask+0x288/0x2a0
[pon sie 12 11:53:44 2019]  [<ffffffff811e84ed>] alloc_pages_vma+0xad/0x250
[pon sie 12 11:53:44 2019]  [<ffffffff811d8ece>] __read_swap_cache_async+0xee/0x140
[pon sie 12 11:53:44 2019]  [<ffffffff811d8f46>] read_swap_cache_async+0x26/0x60
[pon sie 12 11:53:44 2019]  [<ffffffff811d9085>] swapin_readahead+0x105/0x1b0
[pon sie 12 11:53:44 2019]  [<ffffffff811c60f0>] handle_mm_fault+0x1320/0x1820
[pon sie 12 11:53:44 2019]  [<ffffffff810f340c>] ? hrtimer_nanosleep+0xdc/0x210
[pon sie 12 11:53:44 2019]  [<ffffffff8106c747>] __do_page_fault+0x197/0x400
[pon sie 12 11:53:44 2019]  [<ffffffff8106c9d2>] do_page_fault+0x22/0x30
[pon sie 12 11:53:44 2019]  [<ffffffff818519d8>] page_fault+0x28/0x30
[pon sie 12 11:53:44 2019] Mem-Info:
[pon sie 12 11:53:44 2019] active_anon:3530449 inactive_anon:422028 isolated_anon:384
                            active_file:179 inactive_file:100 isolated_file:0
                            unevictable:913 dirty:0 writeback:0 unstable:0
                            slab_reclaimable:9555 slab_unreclaimable:17443
                            mapped:666425 shmem:1068600 pagetables:11052 bounce:0
                            free:35287 free_pcp:0 free_cma:0
[pon sie 12 11:53:44 2019] Node 0 DMA free:15888kB min:64kB low:80kB high:96kB active_anon:0kB inactive_anon:0kB active_file:0kB inactive_file:0kB unevictable:0kB isolated(anon):0kB isolated(file):0kB present:15988kB managed:15888kB mlocked:0kB dirty:0kB writeback:0kB mapped:0kB shmem:0kB slab_reclaimable:0kB slab_unreclaimable:0kB kernel_stack:0kB pagetables:0kB unstable:0kB bounce:0kB free_pcp:0kB local_pcp:0kB free_cma:0kB writeback_tmp:0kB pages_scanned:0 all_unreclaimable? yes
[pon sie 12 11:53:44 2019] lowmem_reserve[]: 0 1811 15874 15874 15874
[pon sie 12 11:53:44 2019] Node 0 DMA32 free:63400kB min:7704kB low:9628kB high:11556kB active_anon:1349712kB inactive_anon:449972kB active_file:164kB inactive_file:172kB unevictable:904kB isolated(anon):768kB isolated(file):0kB present:1987100kB managed:1906332kB mlocked:904kB dirty:0kB writeback:0kB mapped:53540kB shmem:495788kB slab_reclaimable:3864kB slab_unreclaimable:7812kB kernel_stack:400kB pagetables:7000kB unstable:0kB bounce:0kB free_pcp:0kB local_pcp:0kB free_cma:0kB writeback_tmp:0kB pages_scanned:11349276 all_unreclaimable? yes
[pon sie 12 11:53:44 2019] lowmem_reserve[]: 0 0 14062 14062 14062
[pon sie 12 11:53:44 2019] Node 0 Normal free:61860kB min:59812kB low:74764kB high:89716kB active_anon:12772084kB inactive_anon:1238140kB active_file:552kB inactive_file:228kB unevictable:2748kB isolated(anon):768kB isolated(file):0kB present:14663680kB managed:14400224kB mlocked:2748kB dirty:0kB writeback:0kB mapped:2612160kB shmem:3778612kB slab_reclaimable:34356kB slab_unreclaimable:61960kB kernel_stack:3952kB pagetables:37208kB unstable:0kB bounce:0kB free_pcp:0kB local_pcp:0kB free_cma:0kB writeback_tmp:0kB pages_scanned:89423048 all_unreclaimable? yes
[pon sie 12 11:53:44 2019] lowmem_reserve[]: 0 0 0 0 0
[pon sie 12 11:53:44 2019] Node 0 DMA: 2*4kB (U) 3*8kB (U) 3*16kB (U) 0*32kB 3*64kB (U) 2*128kB (U) 0*256kB 0*512kB 1*1024kB (U) 1*2048kB (M) 3*4096kB (M) = 15888kB
[pon sie 12 11:53:44 2019] Node 0 DMA32: 147*4kB (UME) 54*8kB (UME) 458*16kB (UME) 139*32kB (UME) 106*64kB (UME) 51*128kB (UME) 23*256kB (UE) 17*512kB (UE) 3*1024kB (UME) 0*2048kB 5*4096kB (M) = 64252kB
[pon sie 12 11:53:44 2019] Node 0 Normal: 267*4kB (UME) 183*8kB (UME) 230*16kB (UMEH) 215*32kB (UMEH) 86*64kB (UEH) 86*128kB (UMEH) 70*256kB (UMEH) 26*512kB (UMEH) 1*1024kB (U) 0*2048kB 0*4096kB = 61860kB
[pon sie 12 11:53:44 2019] Node 0 hugepages_total=0 hugepages_free=0 hugepages_surp=0 hugepages_size=1048576kB
[pon sie 12 11:53:44 2019] Node 0 hugepages_total=0 hugepages_free=0 hugepages_surp=0 hugepages_size=2048kB
[pon sie 12 11:53:44 2019] 1083770 total pagecache pages
[pon sie 12 11:53:44 2019] 14283 pages in swap cache
[pon sie 12 11:53:44 2019] Swap cache stats: add 81268022, delete 81253739, find 37239561/47307273
[pon sie 12 11:53:44 2019] Free swap  = 14632936kB
[pon sie 12 11:53:44 2019] Total swap = 16662524kB
[pon sie 12 11:53:44 2019] 4166692 pages RAM
[pon sie 12 11:53:44 2019] 0 pages HighMem/MovableOnly
[pon sie 12 11:53:44 2019] 86081 pages reserved
[pon sie 12 11:53:44 2019] 0 pages cma reserved
[pon sie 12 11:53:44 2019] 0 pages hwpoisoned
[pon sie 12 11:53:44 2019] [ pid ]   uid  tgid total_vm      rss nr_ptes nr_pmds swapents oom_score_adj name
[pon sie 12 11:53:44 2019] [  449]     0   449    42126      113      18       3       75             0 lvmetad
[pon sie 12 11:53:44 2019] [  461]     0   461    11311      172      22       3      361         -1000 systemd-udevd
[pon sie 12 11:53:44 2019] [  917]     0   917   151045      242      28       3      730             0 lxcfs
[pon sie 12 11:53:44 2019] [  924]     0   924     7557      409      19       3       80             0 cron
[pon sie 12 11:53:44 2019] [  929]     0   929     1099      288       7       3       36             0 acpid
[pon sie 12 11:53:44 2019] [  944]   112   944    11227      404      25       3      117             0 avahi-daemon
[pon sie 12 11:53:44 2019] [  946]     0   946     6511      375      18       3       77             0 atd
[pon sie 12 11:53:44 2019] [  951]     0   951     6320      398      17       4      227             0 smartd
[pon sie 12 11:53:44 2019] [  954]   104   954    64098      283      28       3      283             0 rsyslogd
[pon sie 12 11:53:44 2019] [  956]   107   956    10792      329      25       3      191          -900 dbus-daemon
[pon sie 12 11:53:44 2019] [  977]   112   977    11196        0      24       3       81             0 avahi-daemon
[pon sie 12 11:53:44 2019] [  982]     0   982   112713      309      73       4      700             0 NetworkManager
[pon sie 12 11:53:44 2019] [  983]     0   983     8863      347      20       3      241             0 openvpn
[pon sie 12 11:53:44 2019] [  986]     0   986    69321      328      37       3      234             0 accounts-daemon
[pon sie 12 11:53:44 2019] [ 1002]     0  1002     3343      226      11       3       41             0 mdadm
[pon sie 12 11:53:44 2019] [ 1011]     0  1011    69277      371      39       4      188             0 polkitd
[pon sie 12 11:53:44 2019] [ 1087]     0  1087     4030      321      13       3      215             0 dhclient
[pon sie 12 11:53:44 2019] [ 1275]     0  1275    16377      341      37       3      185         -1000 sshd
[pon sie 12 11:53:44 2019] [ 1284]     0  1284   211630        0      86       6     9081          -500 dockerd
[pon sie 12 11:53:44 2019] [ 1306]     0  1306     1305      405       9       3       51             0 iscsid
[pon sie 12 11:53:44 2019] [ 1310]     0  1310     1430      876       9       3        0           -17 iscsid
[pon sie 12 11:53:44 2019] [ 1409]     0  1409     4868      367      14       3       73             0 irqbalance
[pon sie 12 11:53:44 2019] [ 1418]     0  1418     4289      313      14       3       39             0 agetty
[pon sie 12 11:53:44 2019] [ 1457]     0  1457   168379        0      65       6     5264          -500 docker-containe
[pon sie 12 11:53:44 2019] [ 2193]     0  2193    10705      145      14       5      154          -500 docker-proxy
[pon sie 12 11:53:44 2019] [ 2229]     0  2229    66420      186      21       5      660          -500 docker-proxy
[pon sie 12 11:53:44 2019] [ 2264]     0  2264    29138      123      16       5      167          -500 docker-proxy
[pon sie 12 11:53:44 2019] [ 2299]     0  2299     1876        0       8       5      347          -999 docker-containe
[pon sie 12 11:53:44 2019] [ 2391]   100  2391      396        0       7       3       29             0 entrypoint.sh
[pon sie 12 11:53:44 2019] [ 2638]   100  2638    12125        0      30       3     7058             0 tor
[pon sie 12 11:53:44 2019] [30130]     0 30130     7160      153      20       3       89             0 systemd-logind
[pon sie 12 11:53:44 2019] [30475]     0 30475    10959      278      23       3     1630             0 systemd-journal
[pon sie 12 11:53:44 2019] [31698]  1001 31698    11319      336      25       3      216             0 systemd
[pon sie 12 11:53:44 2019] [31701]  1001 31701    53717        0      39       3     1509             0 (sd-pam)
[pon sie 12 11:53:44 2019] [31955]   100 31955    24023      294      17       3       72             0 systemd-timesyn
[pon sie 12 11:53:44 2019] [31981]     0 31981    23731      413      49       4      236             0 sshd
[pon sie 12 11:53:44 2019] [32013]  1001 32013    23731      266      48       4      259             0 sshd
[pon sie 12 11:53:44 2019] [32014]  1001 32014     6235      500      17       3      599             0 bash
[pon sie 12 11:53:44 2019] [32194]     0 32194    23731      419      49       3      236             0 sshd
[pon sie 12 11:53:44 2019] [32287]  1001 32287    23788      197      48       3      244             0 sshd
[pon sie 12 11:53:44 2019] [32288]  1001 32288     6229      420      17       3      659             0 bash
[pon sie 12 11:53:44 2019] [32738]  1001 32738 11646105  3547862    9767      28   454793             0 training.py
[pon sie 12 11:53:44 2019] [32754]     0 32754     4286      267      14       3       45             0 nvidia-persiste
[pon sie 12 11:53:44 2019] [  343]     0   343    23731      437      51       3      236             0 sshd
[pon sie 12 11:53:44 2019] [  445]  1001   445    23731      101      49       3      206             0 sshd
[pon sie 12 11:53:44 2019] [  451]  1001   451     6188      480      17       3      514             0 bash
[pon sie 12 11:53:44 2019] [  473]  1001   473     6847      408      18       3        2             0 htop
[pon sie 12 11:53:44 2019] Out of memory: Kill process 32738 (training.py) score 486 or sacrifice child
[pon sie 12 11:53:44 2019] Killed process 32738 (training.py) total-vm:46584420kB, anon-rss:11534960kB, file-rss:2656488kB
```

Why the rest of SWAP is not used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linux OOM killer can still get angry if it actually runs out of memory. There needs to be somewhere in RAM to put the page tables. Swap space is also much slower, which may not be able to page out fast enough to keep up with a high allocation rate.

Going by the last line, training.py was using about 14 GB of RSS. That can put memory pressure on a 16 GB host by itself, not counting overhead required to run the operating system.

Also, in the Mem-Info section, file is low triple digits. Your file caches this low (relative to anon and shmem) is a symptom that all the easy pages are already reclaimed.

Needs more RAM.

Comment: hows about With swapiness 90/99?

Comment: Tweak swappiness and test if you like. In my opinion, swap space is not a good substitute for RAM.

Comment: thats right, but my storage is about 1gb/s fast sofar not mich a problem 8n case

Comment: DRAM is orders of magnitude more bandwidth and lower latency than permanent storage you might use for swap. In a race between the two, at a high allocation rate, memory will fill up before it can be paged out. Maybe you can tune this to not OOM kill, but that takes the penalty of paging back in being super slow.